# Obtaining this effect in Adobe Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, art

How can I obtain this vector effect in Illustrator? Is there a name for this kind of effect? Please, help!

[image: breaking bad]

Comment: You could simply ask http://kentaylor.com.au/ what he uses for tools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt it was made in illustrator vector but it could've been. If so it was a very expensive custom job. More likely its a photo brought into photoshop then adjust levels and maybe use the posterize filter along with some hue/saturation techniques for the coloring.

To do this in illustrator you just need to draw all the different shades as vectors which is a lot easier said then done. There are plenty of tutorials out there if you search for "Illustrator Portrait Tutorial." The one I used when learning doesn't exist anymore. Again though to get to the level of the picture you posted takes a lot of patience and time.

Here's a tutorial that has a similar quality to the picture you posted if you do want to go for it: [Spoongraphics - How to create a beautiful vector portrait in illustrator](http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-create-a-beautiful-vector-portrait-in-illustrator)

You'll notice the first steps in that tutorial is the things I said in Photoshop. Basically you're always going to start by simplifying your photo and getting a tonal quality you want in photoshop. If you then really need it in vector you have to bring it in to illustrator and start tracing.

Comment: Perfect answer. I'll opt by Photoshop!

Comment: I think Ryan said "Start with Photoshop and then bring it into illustrator."